# JSON.NET in a MonoMac application doesn't let me build an mac app package

Tags: c#, .net, json, mono, monomac

I'm trying to build a MonoMac app that uses the JSON.NET library but whenever I try to generate the app installer I see the following error:

```
Merging Mono into app bundle
    /Applications/Development/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MonoDevelop.MonoMac/mmp -o "/tmp/monomac-build-634732855752481110" -n "OfficeDropSync" -a  "/Users/mauricio/projects/mono/winclient/ODWSyncApplication/OfficeDrop.Sync.Business/bin/Release/OfficeDrop.Sync.Business.dll" -a "/Users/mauricio/projects/mono/winclient/ODWSyncApplication/OfficeDrop.Sync.Common/bin/Release/OfficeDrop.Sync.Common.dll" -a "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/lib/mono/4.0/System.dll" -a "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/lib/mono/4.0/System.Xml.dll" -a "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/lib/mono/4.0/System.Core.dll" -a "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/lib/mono/4.0/System.Xml.Linq.dll" -a "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/lib/mono/4.0/System.Drawing.dll" -a "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/lib/mono/4.0/Mono.Data.Sqlite.dll" -a "/Users/mauricio/projects/mono/winclient/thirdparty/log4net.dll" -a "/Users/mauricio/projects/mono/winclient/thirdparty/monomac/src/MonoMac.dll" "/Users/mauricio/projects/mono/winclient/ODWSyncApplication/OfficeDrop.Sync.Mac/bin/Release/OfficeDropSync.exe"
Could not link assemblies: Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.Void Newtonsoft.Json.JsonObjectAttribute::.ctor(Newtonsoft.Json.MemberSerialization)
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethod (Mono.Cecil.MethodReference reference) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkCustomAttribute (Mono.Cecil.CustomAttribute ca) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkCustomAttributes (ICustomAttributeProvider provider) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType (Mono.Cecil.TypeReference reference) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType (Mono.Cecil.TypeReference reference) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkField (Mono.Cecil.FieldReference reference) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkFields (Mono.Cecil.TypeDefinition type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ApplyPreserveInfo (Mono.Cecil.TypeDefinition type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType (Mono.Cecil.TypeReference reference) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.InitializeType (Mono.Cecil.TypeDefinition type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.InitializeAssembly (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition assembly) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Initialize () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoMac.Tuner.Linker.Run (Mono.Linker.Pipeline pipeline, Mono.Linker.LinkContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 Failed to link /Users/mauricio/projects/mono/winclient/ODWSyncApplication/OfficeDrop.Sync.Mac/bin/Release/OfficeDropSync.exe

mmp exited with code 1
```

Has anyone seen this before? Is there a way around this issue?

Answer (score 1):

> Has anyone seen this before?

Yes. This happens when symbols can't be resolved.

In your case it looks like your `mmp` command line does not have any *direct* reference to the json assembly. However some of the assemblies have references to it. The `ResolutionException` occurs when processing the later and when `mmp` resolver is unable to find the assembly referenced.

> Is there a way around this issue?

Manually add a reference to the assembly (that will make sure it will be included) *or* make sure it (the missing json library) can be found by `mmp`.

Comment: I have included the JSON.NET project source code into my project as a separate project that gets included in the MonoMac project, so, there is a direct reference for it.

Comment: and you're sure none of the other assemblies (mainly any pre-compiled ones) are not looking for a separate library ?

Comment: Yes, there are no pre-compiled binaries, I have removed the only one available yesterday and now all we have is the source project.

Comment: Something (loaded) has a reference to something that cannot be found. You need to find out what it is. Look at the list of assemblies given to `mmp` and compare it to what you build. Are both list identical (check the paths carefully against old binaries) ?

Comment: The MonoMac linker is making some magic and removing attributes from my classes (and from the library source, looks like). As I haven't found a way around this I just removed JSON.NET and decided to use a different parset that doesn't use annotations, not ideal, but that's life.

Comment: No magic ;-) and nothing is removed from the code you supply unless you use **link all** (e.g. start with **link sdk**). If you do (use link all) then you need to protect things that cannot be detected via static analysis (e.g. reflection).

Comment: JSON.NET uses reflection to handle this, unfortunately.